# How to use BeautifulSoup to find all the next links

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently scraping all the page of a specific website by presetting a variable called number_of_pages.  Presetting this variable works until a new page is added that I don't know about. For example the code below is for 3 pages, but the website now has 4 pages.

```
base_url = 'https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/Home/Index/?page='
number_of_pages = 3
for i in range(1, number_of_pages, 1):
   url_to_scrape = (base_url + str(i))
```

I would like to use BeautifulSoup to find all the next links on the website to scrape. The code below finds the second URL, but not the third or fourth. How do I build a list of all the pages prior to scraping them?

```
base_url = 'https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/Home/Index/?page='
CrawlRequest = requests.get(base_url)
raw_html = CrawlRequest.text
linkSoupParser = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
page = linkSoupParser.find('div', {'class': 'pagination'})
for list_of_links in page.find('a', href=True, text='next'):
  nextURL = 'https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com' + list_of_links.parent['href']
print (nextURL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different ways to approach the pagination. Here is one of them.

The idea is to *initialize an endless loop and break it once there is no "next" link*:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


with requests.Session() as session:
    page_number = 1
    url = 'https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/Home/Index/?page='
    while True:
        print("Processing page: #{page_number}; url: {url}".format(page_number=page_number, url=url))
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        # check if there is next page, break if not
        next_link = soup.find("a", text="next")
        if next_link is None:
            break

        url = urljoin(url, next_link["href"])
        page_number += 1

print("Done.")
```

If you execute it, you will see the following messages printed:

```
Processing page: #1; url: https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/Home/Index/?page=
Processing page: #2; url: https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/Home/Index/?page=2
Processing page: #3; url: https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/Home/Index/?page=3
Processing page: #4; url: https://securityadvisories.paloaltonetworks.com/Home/Index/?page=4
Done.
```

Note that, to improve on performance and persist cookies across the requests, we are maintaining a web-scraping session with [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).