# Python scraping go to next page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

This is my scraping code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_emails(_links:list):
for i in range(len(_links)):
 new_d = soup(requests.get(_links[i]).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'my_modal_open'})
 if new_d:
   yield new_d[-1]['title']

start=20
while True:
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/?bundesland=&start=20').text, 'html.parser')

results = [i['href'] for i in d.find_all('a')][52:-9]
results = [link for link in results if link.startswith('http://')]
print(list(get_emails(results)))

next_page=soup.find('div', {'class': 'paging'}, 'weiter')

if next_page:

    d=next_page.get('href')
    start+=20
else:
    break
```

And thats the error I get:
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'

When you press the button "weiter" (next page) the urlending changes from "...start=20" to "start=40".
It is in 20s steps because there are 20 results per site.
Does anyone know the reason for the error?

Comment: Nothing in the code here assigns a string to `soup`, which is bound to `BeautifulSoup` imported from `bs4` at the top. You are probably assigning something to it elsewhere, but not in the code here. Your local BeautifulSoup *instance* is called `d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the 'soup' in a variable called 'd'.

So replace the following line:

```
next_page=soup.find('div', {'class': 'paging'}, 'weiter')
```

With this:

```
next_page = d.find('div', {'class': 'paging'}, 'weiter')
```

Comment: yes that works thanks. But python doesnt go to the next side, it just prints out the same email addresses again and again. Do you now why? Or should I open a new question?

Comment: Please take a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43076493/7547749